# How can I correct an "'int' object is not iterable" error using Python?

Tags: python, string, int, typeerror

```
def square_each(nums):
    import math
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i] = nums[i]**2

def sum_list(nums):
    for values in nums:
        sums = sum(values)
        print(sums)

def to_numbers(str_list):
    numbers = [int(strings) for strings in str_list]
    return numbers

def main():
    print("This program computes the sum of the squares of numbers read from a file.")
    filename = input("Please enter the file name:")
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    line = file.readline()
    list1 = line.split(" ")
    numbers = to_numbers(list1)
    square_each(numbers)
    sums = sum_list(numbers)
    print("The sum of the squares of the numbers in the file is{0}".format(sums))

    main()



Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\kathe\Desktop\csc161\lab_function.py", line 35, in <module>

 File "C:\Users\kathe\Desktop\csc161\lab_function.py", line 32, in main
sums = sum_list(numbers)

 File "C:\Users\kathe\Desktop\csc161\lab_function.py", line 16, in sum_list
sums = sum(values)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I opened a file with a list of strings(numbers). Then I used three functions to convert string to numbers, square each number, and sum the list of numbers. The last function, main(), included those three functions. But I have an 'int' object is not iterable error. How can I correct this error here?

Comment: In your sum_list function, remove the for loop and just return sum(nums)

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the comment above, you don't need to run your list through a for loop as the sum function will handle that for you.  In actual fact, your sum_list function is quite redundant.
The working function looks like:

```
def sum_list(nums):
    sums = sum(nums)
    return sums
```

I'd eliminate that function and just do:

```
def square_each(nums):
    import math
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i] = nums[i]**2

def to_numbers(str_list):
    numbers = [int(strings) for strings in str_list]
    return numbers

def main():
    print("This program computes the sum of the squares of numbers read from a file.")
    filename = input("Please enter the file name:")
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    line = file.readline()
    list1 = line.split(" ")
    numbers = to_numbers(list1)
    square_each(numbers)
    sums = sum(numbers) # <- this instead of your function presuming that you are feeding a list
    print("The sum of the squares of the numbers in the file is{0}".format(sums))

main()
```

Some reading for the sum function in python:
http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Recursion/pythondsCalculatingtheSumofaListofNumbers.html

The reason I chose this example is because it shows what  I believe your function is trying to achieve - if your input was not already a list; but in your case, it is not really required.